# Cant send email with html body and attachment

Tags: linux, command-line, email, attachments, mailutils

I can not send email with html body with attachment.
Command1:

```
echo "<html><b>Hello</b></html>" | mail -s "Subject #1" -a "content-type: text/html" asdf@gmail.com
```

Command2:

```
echo "<html><b>Hello</b></html>" | mail -s "Subject #2" -a "content-type: text/html" asdf@gmail.com -A "/Users/asdf/Downloads/00000001.pdf"
```

Command1 works fine. I see email with html body.

In 2nd command, body is in not in html format.

Please let me know If I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which mail tool you are using (and which version) but if it is GNU mailutils you probably run into this bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918806#22
A workaround is to use command line option -M (or --mime) to compose MIME messages.

Answer (score 0):

Attachments are always sent using multipart MIME messages, so the root content type describes the *multipart structure itself*, and each part has *its own* Content-Type header inside. You should see `Content-Type: multipart/related` if you take a look at such a message's source.

AFAIK, neither mailutils nor mailx have an option to change the Content-Type of the body part separately.

Comment: any alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

With a current version of GNU Mailutils, this can be accomplished by using `mailx` as follows:

```
echo "<html><b>Hello</b></html>" | mailx --content-type="application/pdf" --attach=/Users/asdf/Downloads/00000001.pdf --content-type="text/html" --subject="Subject #2" asdf@gmail.com
```

Note that `--content-type` is a positional option referring to *all* following attachments (if there are more than one) and the last value specified is then also used for the message body (this is why it's changed again at the end).